# How do I read several lines in Matlab with textscan?

Tags: matlab, textscan

I used this :

```
weights=fopen('indices.txt');
weights=textscan(weights, '%d %d %d %d %d %d %d')
```

but this only reads the first line of my file.
my file looks like this :

```
0 90 100 5 0 0 0 (class)
19 5 0 0 0 0 0 (class2)
5 5 0 0 0 0 0 (class3)
-10 -5 0 0 0 0 0 (class4)
```

And I don't need what's in the brackets

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

For this case, you can do the following:

```
fid = fopen('indices.txt');
num_ints = 7;
num_rows = 4;

format = [repmat('%d ', 1, num_ints), '%s'];
weights = textscan(fid, format, num_rows);
weights = [weights{1:num_ints}];
fclose(fid);
```

The downside of course is that you have to know the number of rows that you're reading beforehand. You could try calling textscan in a loop, but that doesn't seem to be how it's meant to be used (and I would rather use fgetl instead if I'm trying to read the file line-by-line).

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
fh = fopen('indices.txt');
resC = textscan(fh, '%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %s', 1000);
res = cell2mat(resC(1:7))
fclose(fh);
```

`textscan` will only read (and return) up to the available number of lines. Note however, that `textscan` allocates memory for the number of lines you provide (1000 here), so you want to choose something "wise" there.